# Mathematica with a Touchpad

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to make it so that you do not need to rely on keyboard presses to manipulate a 3D graphic. I've done some searching, but I can't find a way to make it so that Mathematica will recognize something else as equivalent to a Shift or Ctrl press. Anyone have any ideas on how I could make a 3D Graphic fairly interactive with only a touchpad? (Pinch-to-Zoom, Two-Finger Panning, etc.)? Thanks in advance.

By the way, I'm running a Logitech T651 on a Mac (I am using the Mac-compatible touchpad). The Pinch feature on the touchpad currently causes all of Mathematica to be magnified, including any interfaces or lines of code. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: " GestureHandler".... check this function

Comment: OH! Yeah, I, unfortunately, forgot to mention that I tried an example from the Mathematica Documentation using GestureHandler, but it failed to acknowledge that a pinch had occurred.

Comment: you shall post it here...someone might help

Comment: The easiest way is probably to get for example *Better Touch Tool* from the App Store and map some gesture to those keys. Guaranteed to work and only takes like a minute.

Comment: To my knowledge, Better Touch Tool does not support Logitech touchpads.

Comment: Also, as I'm fiddling with BTT, it does not appear to be capable of holding a key, just a quick press. For Mathematica to perform as desired, Shift, Ctrl, etc. must be continuously depressed.

Comment: @Matt I was too fast on the trigger, sorry.